# MYSQL PHP Inner Join Compare different values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

I have this two columns:

[image]

The first column name is TAGS and the second column name is PORTTAG.

I want to get all tags.nome that are not to be used on porttag.tag with porttag.port = 1

```html
$mysqli->query("SELECT nome FROM tags INNER JOIN porttag ON porttag.tag != tags.nome WHERE porttag.port = '".$_GET['edit']."'");
```

But without success!

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you need to use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT nome 
FROM   tags t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   porttag p 
                   WHERE  p.tag = tags.nome AND p.port = 1)
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get all tags.nome that are not to be used on porttag.tag with porttag.port = 1

This makes me think of this:

```
select t.*
from tags t
where not exists (select 1 from porttag pt where pt.port = 1 and pt.tag = t.nome);
```

However, you have something very strange in your data model.  The link between the tables should be based on the id not the name.